# TCP Java question

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am learning about using sockets with Java and have encountered a problem for a script I wish to write. I have written a basic script for a client and a server and now wish to expand on it. (It's more or less the one specified here : [Link to Oracle tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)).

Now I wish to adapt this program to have it do a few things differently, I'd like the server, on connection of the client, to send a list of all files in the home directory to the server, the client then picks one out and details of that file are sent back to the client (the equivalent of an ls -a in terminal). Then the client can type yes or no, deciding if they want to download the file or not.

I think it should be simple enough, so I'd like to do it myself so that I can learn, can anyone tell me how I can begin, or some examples I can look at, because I have tried searching and can find nothing.

Thanks very much.

Edit : How can I send a list of the files in a directory, is there a function to get this list ?

Comment: We're not going to write the code for you. Start hacking away at it, and ask us if you have _specific_ problems implementing your idea.

Comment: Good thing I specified that I didn't want anyone to write my code and asked for where I could look at examples and functions for where I can LEARN how to do this myself. If you're not going to be helpful, you could at least not be condescending.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @FattyBolger! Matt is right, you haven't asked a _specific_ question. It sounds like you have an idea of what you want your program to do, so give it a try. When you run into something that you can't figure out, come back, post some code, and ask a question that can be answered objectively. If you're looking for more open-ended discussion of programming, then you might look at [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Isaac Truett, thanks a lot for the helpful response! I have edited my post with a more specific problem that was annoying me now.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt be difficult once you have set up a basic request/response example. You basically will have to set up a switch case kind of construct inside the server that will decide what to send based upon what it recieves.

Something like

```
if recievedCommand = Nothing
   Send File List
if recievedCommand = FileName
   Send File info
...
```

And so on.
Hope this gets your ball rolling

Comment: I see, so on first connect of the client I send some distinct message to the server which triggers it to run another method sending a list of files to the client, and from there I can just use readLine to read the clients messages to the server. Thanks a lot for clearing that up. Do you know how I would send all files in a directory by any chance ?

Comment: File[] fileList = new File(dirName).listFiles() - Iterate and build a string of fileList[i].getName()'s and send this over as response.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any default value I can give dirName in this case for the home directory ?

Comment: The home directory of the user running the server is given by `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

Comment: You need to do a file handling example too. Use dirName = "." for current dir, ".." = for parent dir, "/" for root dir. Getting to users home dir may take some work - use Google. Can you handle reading file and changing directories?

Answer (score 0):

The protocol is of importance here. Either you can design a text protocol like the KnockKnockProtocol in the example. e.g:

```
client: LIST
server: FILES foo.txt bar.txt
client: DETAILS bar.txt
server: DETAILS bar.txt 123421 0644 myuser mygroup
client: GET bar.txt
server: FILEDATA bar.txt <base64-encoded content or such>
client: QUIT
```

But there are already many of those around, designing good protocols is hard and it is quite easy to write bugs in parsers etc. It's generally not worth it.

But... You use java for both client and server and java can serialize objects so you can send whole objects through network streams. That way you don't have to bother with parsing issues.

Just read the network socket through [ObjectInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and write through [ObjectOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). That way you can have classes that model the requests and responses of your protocol.

```
public interface Request implements Serializable {
}

public class ListFilesRequest implements Request {
}

public class FileDetailsRequest implements Request {
    public String fileName;
}

public class DownloadFileRequest implements Request {
    public String fileName;
}

public interface Response implements Serializable {
}

public class FileListResponse implements Response {
    public String[] fileNames;
}

public class FileDetailsResponse implements Response {
    public String fileName;
    public int fileSize;
    public int fileMode;
}

public class FileDataResponse implements Response {
    public String fileName;
    public byte[] fileData;
}
```

Then server could do something like:

```
ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
ObjectOutputStream objOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
Object requestObject = objInput.readObject();
Response responseObject = null;

if (requestObject instanceOf ListFilesRequest) {
    FileListResponse response = new FileListResponse();
    response.fileNames = new String[] { "foo.txt", "bar.txt" };
    responseObject = response;
}
else if (requestObject instanceOf FileDetailsRequest) {
    FileDetailsRequest request = (FileDetailsRequest)requestObject;
    String fileName = request.fileName;
    ...
}

objOutput.writeObject(responseObject);
```

...or something like this.